# If $M \cong T \oplus F$, then $T \cong \text{Tors}(M)$ where $T$ is torsion and $F$ is free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Define $\text{Tors}(M)$ to be the torsion submodule of a module $M$ over an integral domain $R$. The claim is now the following.

> Claim: Let $M$ be a module over an integral domain $R$. If $M \cong T \oplus F$ where $T$ is torsion and $F$ is free, then $T \cong \text{Tors}(M)$.

I can't even see a clear direction for the proof but apparently notes I found online put it off as obvious which is definitely not to me.

My attempt stuck just after writing down the definitions. Since $T$ is torsion, then $T = \text{Tors}(T)$ i.e. for every element $t \in T$, there is a nonzero $r \in R$ such that $rt = 0_T$. Now an element $\text{Tors}(M)$ are elements $m \in M$ such that there exists nonzero $s \in R$ such that $sm = 0_M = (0_T, 0_F)$. From here, I don't see how to construct the isomorphism. Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since $R$ is a domain, the free module $F$ doesn't have any (nonzero) torsion. So what must the image of a torsion element in $M$ look like in $T\oplus F$?

Comment: Looks like $(t, 0)$ where $t \in T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$

First, notice that if $x \in Tors(M)$, if $\phi$ denotes the isomorphism $M \simeq T \oplus F$ then $\phi(x)$ is a torsion element.

For a generic element $(a, b) \in T \oplus F$ in order to be a torsion element there should exist a $k \in R$ such that $k \cdot (a,b)= (ka, kb)=(0,0)$. Since $F$ is a free module over an integral domain this means that $b$ must be equal to $0$. It is not difficult to conclude from this point.

Comment: I still don't see the isomorphism though. I get that if $(a, b) \in \text{Tors}(T \oplus F)$, then $b = 0$ since $F$ is free. Is the isomorphism $\text{Tors}(M) \to T$ is given by the restriction of $\phi$ (denoting the isomorphism $M \to T \oplus F$) from $m$ to elements that look like $(t_m, 0)$?

Comment: @devianceee In full generality, a linear map $M\rightarrow N$ restricts to a linear map $\operatorname{Tors}(M)\rightarrow\operatorname{Tors}(N)$ (i.e. linear maps map torsion elements to torsion elements). Apply this to an isomorphism and its inverse to see that isomorphic modules have isomorphic torsion parts.

Comment: @Thorgott this is very helpful, thank you!